# Import a vcf file without using an intent

Tags: android

Can you import a vcf file in Android without using an intent?

Answer (score 1):

Android has nothing built-in for vCard import, in terms of a traditional Java API. There is [this third-party library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android) and perhaps others.

Comment: I see that is why I could not find anything, I look into this vCard thing. Thanks!