# How do I open a .vcf from an intent filer?

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

Hello I'm trying to make an app where I can open .vcf files. Primarily from texting apps and I've gotten it to work where I can open my app using the following code in and androidmanifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".Home"
       android:parentActivityName=".MapsActivity">

       <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="MapsActivity" />
           <intent-filter android:label="Open iLocation">
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                  <data android:scheme="content" />
                  <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
           </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter android:label="Open iLocation">
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
           <data android:scheme="file" />
           <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
           <data android:pathPattern=".*\.vcf" />
           <data android:pathPattern=".*\..*\.vcf" />
           <data android:pathPattern=".*\..*\..*\.vcf" />
           <data android:pathPattern=".*\..*\..*\..*\.vcf" />
           <data android:pathPattern=".*\..*\..*\..*\..*\.vcf" />
           <data android:host="*" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

That opens my .Home file but I'm not sure how I get the data from the file. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879428/import-a-vcf-file-without-using-an-intent

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm not trying to import the contact to my phonebook, I'm trying to get data from it (Name, email, website, etc)

Comment: If you read the answer to that question, you will notice that I point you to a project to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll give it ago but I only need to get the website from the  contact so I want to keep it as small as possible. I think I might to use getIntent(); if I can't get this to work. Do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `Uri` representing the content you are to view or edit, call `getIntent().getData()`. Then, you can use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the actual content you are offering to view or edit, given that `Uri`.

In terms of vCard itself, Android has nothing built-in for vCard parsing, in terms of a traditional Java API. Your choices are:

- Use [this third-party library](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android)
- Find another third-party library or other vCard parsing hunk of code (e.g., the Contacts app should have some in there somewhere)
- Roll your own parser sufficient for your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { 
     mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
     mIntent.setType("text/x-vcard");
     startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1);
} else {
     mIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
     mIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
     mIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(contactFolder), "text/x-vcard");
     startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(mIntent, "Select File"), 2);
}
```

And get intent result.....

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri mUri = data.getData();
        if (mUri != null) {
            String mFilePath;
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                mFilePath = mUri.getPath();
            } else {
                mFilePath = getPathFromURI(mUri);
            }
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, RestoreActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("filepath", mFilePath);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong...\nPlease try again...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private String getPathFromURI(Uri mUri) {
    String mDocId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(mUri);
    String[] mSplit = mDocId.split(":");
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + mSplit[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually not a very complicated process. Just ensure that you get the `Uri` from FileProvider and you'll be able to trigger the Phone Book Chooser Intent.

Then, you'll be able to import your contacts with `.vcf`.

```kotlin
private fun saveVcfFile(savedVCard: File) {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider",
            savedVCard
        )
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, contentResolver.getType(uri))
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        startActivity(intent)
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        // TODO: Handle Exception
    }
}
```