# How to get all data from Qr code like Name, Email, Contact info programetically?

Tags: java, android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I use ZXingScannerView for scan Barcode and it shows only barcode type and content. But I want to extract full data from content like name, birth date, etc...

Scan result shown in the below image, its result of business card scan, it gives mixed content how can I extract all fields?

Here Only two methods for this

**How i separate all field like name, email, number, etc..**

```
String format= rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString());
String Content=rawResult.getText());
```

[image]

Comment: The data is probably described according to the third edition of this specification. [vCard Format Specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6350) Various tools and libraries can be found by searching with VCARD PARSER ANDROID. For examples. [mangstadt/ez-vcard](https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard), [VCardParser.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/vcard/+/jb-dev/java/com/android/vcard/VCardParser.java), [How do I open a .vcf from an intent filer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35880241/9014308)

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the content by lines first, then decide how to deal with each line.

```
String[] lines = content.split("\n");
for (String line : lines){
    String[] typeAndValue = line.split("[:;]", 2);
    String type = typeAndValue[0];
    String value = typeAndValue[1];
    // ...do the voodoo that you do...
}
```

Comment: But in some line only has :  not both :;

Comment: That's a regular expression. The brackets mean 'match any of these characters.' So each line will be split on either the first colon (:), or the first semi-colon (;). The first line will yield type = "BEGIN", and value = "VCARD".

Comment: In that case, it looks like you could simplify the regular expression to just “:”. At this point though, I’d encourage you to read up on regular expressions and do some experiments with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class ResultParser which is included in the zxing library.

```
...
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import com.google.zxing.client.result.ParsedResult;
import com.google.zxing.client.result.ResultParser;
...
ParsedResult parsedResult = ResultParser.parseResult(rawResult);
switch (parsedResult.getType()) {
    case ADDRESSBOOK:
        AddressBookParsedResult addressResult = (AddressBookParsedResult) parsedResult;
        String[] addresses = addressResult.getAddresses();
        String[] phoneNumbers = addressResult.getPhoneNumbers();
        String[] emails = addressResult.getEmails();
        ...
```